# Does Rails have tags for expiring a cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, tags

Our app uses `Rails.cache` in the controller to cache some items outside the scope of the view (like meta tags), then uses fragment_caching on the bulk of the view.

The view caches **one main model**, but we have used data from **5 other models** (not connected by an Association) inside that main cache. It's easy to expire the fragment with a sweeper on the main model, but those additional models also change and need to trigger this page to expire.

We can't use a regexp route for deleting the cache keys because we have to reference this cache entry by only the main model -- the other models are determined by an expensive query that we perform inside the cache block in the controller.

Does Rails 3 have a way to essentially use **tags** to mark a cache entry, so we can trash it when any of the 6 models on the page change, but we can still find the cache entry from only the main model's key?

---

Here's some dummy code to express the idea:

**In the controller**

```
@cache_key = "/page/#{params[:name]}/#{params[:id]}"
unless fragment_exist? ( { :slug => @cache_key })
  # run our processes here that will be needed in the view, 
  # then cache the data that is used outside the view
  Rails.cache.write(@cache_key, { (data goes here) } )
  # run our expensive query here:
  @similar_pages = Page.pricey_query!.limit(5).all
else 
  cached = Rails.cache.read(@cache_key)
end
```

**In the view**

```
- cache( {:slug => @cache_key} ) do
 - @similar_pages.each do |page|
  = image_tag page.photos.first.image.url
  -# more pretty stuff here
```

**My goal:**

- **Me:** "Oh, page @cache_key has changed, let's expire it!"
- **Rails:** `Okay, easy!`
- **Me:** "One of the similar pages changed their first photo, what do I do?"
- **Rails:** `Umm... #(*$^*@ .. does ... not ... compute.`

Comment: Some caching systems have more features than others. Which are you intending to use?

Comment: I haven't found one yet that supports a tag-like system yet. Neither the built-in caching, cache_fu nor cache_money support a tag-like system.

Comment: Have you had a look at creating an Observer to manage this for you?

Comment: I run into the same issue as with the Sweeper -- i need to access the cached item by one key, but i need to be able to expire it by any of 6 "phrases". I'll explain in the question.

Comment: Also meant to say that none of the available cache stores like filestore or memcached seem to support this concept.

Comment: You may need to invent this sort of thing yourself, sadly. What you might do is leverage the memcached list manipulation methods so you can add things to an existing tag. Otherwise you need to re-think your caching strategy to avoid these kinds of dependencies, or lower your cache timeout to a few minutes so that any sort of slip isn't a big deal.

Comment: You were right tadman, I had to come up with my own solution. It seems to work very well for my purposes, and it was the best route I could use to preserve resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as tadman states in the comments of the question, I had to invent my own solution, since Rails doesn't technically allow tags in the sense that I needed them. Here's a generalized solution for those interested in doing something similar:

I created a new table called `SimilarPages`:

```
create_table :similar_pages, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.integer :page_id, :similar_page_id
  # you could also do `t.string :tag_name` or similar
end
add_index :similar_pages, :page_id
add_index :similar_pages, :similar_page_id
```

Technically, I could do a self-referential `has_many` relationship on `Pages`, but I decided not to since I don't ever need to reference it that way. I just created a simple `SimilarPage` model:

```
class SimilarPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :similar_page, :class_name => 'Page'
end
```

Then using `ar-extensions` (because I'm lazy, and also because I wanted to do this in one INSERT statement), I do this within the cache block:

```
SimilarPage.delete_all("page_id = '#{@page_id}'")
SimilarPage.import [:page_id, :similar_page_id], @similar_pages.collect {|s| SimilarPage.new(:page_id=>@page_id,:similar_page_id=>s.id)}
```

In my `expire_cache_for` method of my Observer, I do this:

```
SimilarPage.where(:similar_page_id => expiring_page.id).all.each do |s|
  ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(/page_show__#{s.page_id}__.*/) 
  # the regexp is for different currencies being cached ^
  Rails.cache.delete("page_show_#{s.page_id}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent explanation of how Rails generates tags for content expiration in this video http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/02/19/episode-8-memcached

The short if it is if you pass your entire object into the cache it will generate a cache key that that uses the timestamp which will get updated when you change your object.

Comment: Just a note, the video above is for memcached, but the cahche key generation is not specific to that

Answer (score 0):

Cashier may be helpful. "Tag based caching"

```
# in your view
cache @some_record, :tag => 'some-component'

# later
Cashier.expire 'some-component'
```

https://github.com/twinturbo/cashier